# XSLT text to large integer

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, altova, map-force

I'm attempting to create an XSLT mapping that properly converts a fairly large integer value coming through in a text field into the appropriate integer value.  The problem is that since 1.0 only supports converting to type number, I get a value like `1.234567890E9` back for input of `"1234567890"`

I'm using Altova MapForce with XSLT1.0 as the coding platform.  XSLT2.0 doesn't appear to be an option, as the XSLT has to be processed using a pre-existing routine that only supports XSLT1.0

By default Mapforce generates 
     `<xsl:value-of select="string(floor(number(string(.))))"/>` 
and I've tried every combination of functions I can think of, but always get a float for large values.

Further testing shows the problem lies in Mapforce, which insists on using the number() function when mapping from text to int.

Comment: If the value coming in is already an integer, why do you need to process it at all?

Comment: @michael It's technically coming in as a text datatype, but should be all digits.  Mapforce automatically tries to do a translation.

Comment: Technically, it's coming in as no type at all, since XML has no data types - unless there is an accompanying schema. Using either `<xsl:copy-of>` or `<xsl:value-of>` should pass it from input to output *as is*.

Comment: Which processor are you using, anyway? I can't even reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm using the MapForce built-in processor during development.  I know one option is to just edit the XSLT after generation and remove any translation code on that field, but I thought surely XSLT 1.0 has SOME way of converting something to an integer.

Comment: ..and yes, the source xsd defines the node as xs:text, while the target xsd (which is part of a pre-processing step to bring the data into a database) defines the node as xs:int.

Comment: "*but I thought surely XSLT 1.0 has SOME way of converting something to an integer*" Of course, but if that 'something' already *is* an integer... Perhaps you should rephrase your question, because right now it's not clear what the exact issue is. If the only problem is that the application you are using suggests an unreasonable transformation - and I would definitely describe `string(floor(number(string(.))))` as unreasonable - then the solution is to ignore such suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies within Mapforce, so I've decided to let mapforce generate it's code, then overwrite it for this one field that's causing all the trouble.

@Tobias @Michael  Thanks to you both for your help.  I've +1'ed both your answers and a few comments since your help led to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try and move this forward by answering a question that you did not ask, but perhaps should have. Suppose you have the following input:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <value>1234567890000000.9</value>
    <value>9876543210000000</value>
</input>
```

and you want to make sure that the input values (which are all *numbers*, but some of them are not *integers*) are converted to integers at the output, you could apply the following transformation:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <output>    
        <xsl:for-each select="input/value">
            <value><xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '#')"/></value>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

to obtain the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <value>1234567890000001</value>
   <value>9876543210000000</value> 
</output>
```

Note that the results here are rounded, not floored.

Comment: I think this is now very specifically a MapForce issue rather than an XSLT issue.  Mapforce is forcing use of the number() function

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "forcing use of the number() function".

Comment: When mapping a text type to an int type using XSLT 1.0, Mapforce use a transform of "string(floor(number(string())))"

Comment: As I said earlier, if that is the issue here, ignore the Mapforce-generated code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that mapforce isn't using xslt-2.0?

If I do in XSLT-1.0 (with either saxon or Altova's processor):

```
<xsl:value-of select="number('1234567890')"/>
```

I get -> `1234567890`

If I use XSLT-2.0 I get -> `1.23456789E9`

So I think it is very strange that an XSLT 1 transformation supposedly returns you the floating point representation of the number.

Formatting the number with `format-number(1.23456789E9,'#')` will <s>always</s> give you `1234567890` in both XSLT-1.0 and 2.0.  ***Edit:*** saxon will not convert 1.23456789E9 to number in xslt-1.0, altova's processor however will.

Comment: I just tried using Saxon to process the XSLT Mapforce generated and still got 1.234567890E9, so the issue lies in the Mapforce generated code which looks like "string(floor(number(string(.))))"

Comment: That's strange, I cannot get saxon to output a floating point number with XSLT-1.0, which saxon version did you try?

Comment: I have the latest 64bit .NET version.  Did you use the transform with the number() function?

Comment: Well the latest version is an XSLT-2.0 processor, did you check the stylesheet that mapforce genrated? Are you absolutely sure it is not an xslt-2.0 stylesheet?

Comment: Yes, the stylesheet is version 1.0

Comment: ...Although, as I look at the command line output, it shows the message "Running an XSLT 1 stylesheet with an XSLT 2 processor"

Comment: Do you have to use .NET? Otherwise try running it with Saxon 6.5

Comment: @DataMasseur "*it shows the message "Running an XSLT 1 stylesheet with an XSLT 2 processor"*" Then you **are** using a XSLT 2.0 processor (Saxon 8 or 9, judging by the error message). Not sure how all this helps, though. Do you know which processor will you be using in the *real* implementation?

Comment: I've decided to just let MapForce generate it's code, then manually overwrite it afterward, as I've verified that works just fine.